# Redirecting Shell output to SNS

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have the below line in my bash shell script;

```
 inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%T %:e %w%f' --timefmt "%a, %b %d %l:%M.%S"  ${basedir} | grep "${filetype}"
```

This will output a line like **"Mon, May 01  9:29.20 DELETE /home/ubuntu/test/test.php"** whenever that line is executed.

Is it it possible to pipeline above output directly to AWS SNS? I tried using jq to format the output into json before redirecting it but there is no output when used as below.

```
inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%T %:e %w%f' --timefmt "%a, %b %d %l:%M.%S"  ${basedir} | grep "${filetype}" | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")'
```

And directly pipping the output will not work.

```
inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%T %:e %w%f' --timefmt "%a, %b %d %l:%M.%S"  ${basedir} | grep "${filetype}" | aws  sns publish --topic-arn "${sns}"
```

Comment: what happens when you just pour the result of `grep` to stdout?

Comment: why do you need to format to json? is seems you need to parse it onto request parameters (see [a sample request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_DeleteTopic.html#API_DeleteTopic_Example_Example_Request)). by the way, why not use the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html)?

Comment: I get the output i want as a string. 
ex:
"Mon, May 01 9:29.20 DELETE /home/ubuntu/test/test.php"

Comment: I'm trying to use the CLI but from what I understand I need to pass a JSON string to it?

Comment: whoops i didn't notice, scratch that :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference in the documentation to the `aws` command being able to receive input from `stdin`, so it seems there's no way to do that.

You can pass all arguments as json, though, with `--cli-input-json`, but it has no use in our case.

You did not specify which field you want to populate with the output of `inotifywait`, but assuming you want to pass a `message`, all you need is to redirect the output to an [option value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html#synopsis):

```sh
get_message() {
    inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%T %:e %w%f' --timefmt "%a, %b %d %l:%M.%S"  ${basedir} | grep "${filetype}"
}
aws sns publish --topic-arn "${sns}" --message "$(get_message)"
```